relation between $E[x]$-module and $F[x]$-module when $E$ is a subfield of $F$
Let $F$ be a field and $E$ be a subfield $F$. Let $X$ be a $n\times n$ matrix with entries in the field $E$.  We can give the $n$-dimensional vector space $E^n$ over $E$, a $E[x]$-module structure by saying $x.(e_1,\dots,e_n)=X\bar{e}$, where $\bar{e}=(e_1,\dots,e_n)^t$. Since the entries of $X$ can also be considered over $F$ as well, in a similar way, we get that $F^n$ is a $F[x]$-module. What is the relation between these two modules?
I think it is natural to think about tensor product but I can't formulate it.

The $E[x]$-module structure of $E^n$ is given by
$$E[x]\to\operatorname{End}_E(E^n)=M_n(E)$$
which maps $x$ to a specific endomorphism of $E^n$. Tensor product both sides with $F$ and
$$F[x]\to\operatorname{End}_F(F^n)=M_n(F)$$
